# Fire event when geolocation is enabled or disabled in browser

Tags: javascript, browser

I'd like to show or hide html when geolocation is enabled in the browser.

I'd like to do this based on the user interaction, if they click confirm, they get the html, if they deny they don't.

If the page loads, and the permission is granted I'd also like to show the html and if it isn't it shouldn't.

I've reviewed the following.

```js
navigator.permissions.query({name:'geolocation'}).then(function(permissionStatus) {

    //console.log('geolocation permission state is ', permissionStatus.state);

    permissionStatus.onchange = function() {

        if (permissionStatus.state == 'granted ') {

            console.log('geolocation permission state has changed to ', this.state);

        }

    };

});
```

And to check on page load.

```
navigator.permissions && navigator.permissions.query({name: 'geolocation'}).then(function(PermissionStatus) {

    if( PermissionStatus.state == 'granted' ) {

        console.log('hello');

    }

});
```

Yet none of this is logging.

My code above is wrapped in `(function( $ ) { })( jQuery );` as I'm using jQuery here too. I've removed all my code apart from the above to ensure that's not the issue but I'm still unable to track change events and check geolocation on page load.

Answer (score 0):

The onchange section was not working as I was not taking the actual event for my if statement.

```
if ( permissionStatus.state == 'granted' ) {
```

Should have been

```
if ( this.state == 'granted ' ) {
```